# What is protobuf-net SerializeWithLengthPrefix tag argument for?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

This method accepts as the last argument an integer, but I'm not sure I understand what I would use it for exactly.

```
Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, object, PrefixStyle.Base128, [tag]);
```

The same holds true for the corresponding Deserialize method.

Is it just a way to tag messages to add some sort of "querying" capabilities on deserialization to filter out unwanted messages or does it have any other usages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, it is an additional marker that *can* be (although does not have to be) used to note the "type" of the message being added, since the presumption (when using the `*WithLengthPrefix` approach) is that there are multiple messages in the same stream.

By being included, it also means that the entire *composite* stream is **itself** an entirely valid protobuf message.

Ways of using this:

- you can serialize a `List<Foo>`, and then repeatedly deserialize (with-length-prefix) individual `Foo` items, or vice-versa
- with a heterogeneous set of objects, you can use the `Serializer.NonGeneric` API to allow type-resolution based on the tag, i.e. the code equivalent of "if 1 then Invoice; if 2 then Order, if 3 then skip it, if 4 then Customer", etc - this is especially useful if using a `NetworkStream` as a message-sending device. This approach (using a different tag per type) allows you to read objects off the stream, and deserialize them correctly, without knowing in advance the *type* of the next message

It is possible to omit this if you want - just pass zero (IIRC). This will save (typically) a byte per message appended, but: it means that the stream is no longer a valid protobuf itself. It can still be read, of course, by passing zero when reading.

Comment: Why does including the tag make it a valid protobuf message?
Can't you deserialize individual items in a list without the tag?

Comment: Also, type resolution using tag has to be carried out by the application code, right?

Comment: @Simone it makes the *composite* message a valid protobuf, because `repeated MessageType` (in .proto) is encoded as a sequence of "[tag][length][payload]...[tag][length][payload]". Hence with the tag it is a valid protobuf, and without: it isn't. Re type resolution; normally yes, since it is intentionally platform independent; however, protobuf-net does also include some *additional* support for including some limited type information on the wire.